# iOS - Swift 3 - Bluetooth background

Tags: swift, bluetooth, background, foreground

i am trying to make bluetooth running while in background and i *exactly* setup my project as described in apple doc and somehow is still does not trigger in background... my setup:

```
Uses blueooth LE accessories
```

in project capabilities set, in info.plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>bluetooth-central</string>
</array>
```

My bluetooth service singleton:

```
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothService: NSObject {
    
    var manager: CBCentralManager!
    var characteristic: CBCharacteristic!
    
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral!
    let peripheral_name: String = "name"
    
    let service_uuid: CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "uuid")
    
    static let shared = BluetoothService()
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
    
}

extension BluetoothService: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("centralManagerDidUpdateState: \(central.state.rawValue)")
        if (central.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn) {
            self.manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [service_uuid], options: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("didDiscover peripheral")
        if (peripheral.name == self.peripheral_name) {
            self.manager.stopScan()
            self.peripheral = peripheral
            self.peripheral.delegate = self
            self.manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("didConnect")
        peripheral.discoverServices([service_uuid])
    }
    
}

extension BluetoothService: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        print("didDiscoverServices")
        for service in peripheral.services! {
            let currentService = service as CBService
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

When i start the app, it DOES NOT discover any peripherals in foreground and background...

BUT when i run:

```
self.manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
```

it works just in the foreground.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you run

```
self.manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [service_uuid], options: nil)
```

what works for you is:

```
self.manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
```

the difference is that you defined withServices in your example. If you search for peripherals with Services you need to be sure that the serviceUUID is part of the advertisement data of your bluetooth device. It can be that maybe the peripheral has a service but this does not mean that it will be part of your advertisement data.

Side information: If you run scanForPeripherals and withServices is nil, it will not run in background. For background excecution you need to define services.

P.S. if you scan and find a peripheral didDiscover will be called. One variable is "advertisementData". This will be the variable to check if you want to know if your serviceUUID is part of the advertisement data.

Comment: Can you share a code example on how to print UUIDs services by scanning devices in foreground?